# For nCr and nPr, what mnemonic does the "r" stand for ??

Tags: probability, statistics

I get that n stands for number, and is a stats convention for number of trials
but what does the r stand for ??

Comment: While "n" indeed probably stand for "number", I think the "n" in nCr is there because because many many people used n to designate a natural number before. So, I don't think that nCr was build with the idea, oh let's take n because it means number, but more, oh let's take n because everybody use this letter to denote a natural number and this is what you need for combinatorics.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it stands for anything. It's just $r$. Some authors use $k$ instead. That doesn't stand for anything either.

Comment: But maybe it does?  Who was the first person that used the r ?

Comment: @JackOfAll do you really expect that to be known in the history books? That's such a specific event.... also why does it matter?

Comment: It matters to me!